# P(P(N)) is equinumerous to the set of real functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I need to show that (the power set of power set of N)   **P(P(N)) is equinumerous to the set of real functions.**

I know that P(N) is equinumerous to R, thus it is equivalent to show that $\{0,1\}^R $ is equinumerous to $R^R$.  But I can't convince myself of this claim, let alone showing it.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Can you prove inequality in one direction?

Comment: And for the other direction, remember that $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\cong \mathbb R$ and think about graphs ...

Comment: @Henning Makholm I use [0,1] instead of R for convenience.
in one direction, I use the identity map from $\{0,1\}^{[0,1]}$ to ${[0,1]}^{[0,1]}$.  In the other direction. I consider functions as sets of ordered pairs, and sending functions point by point, ${(0.r_1r_2r_3.....,0.s_1s_2s_3....)}$ to ${(0.r_1s_1r_2s_2....,1)}$.